# the Graph error : only rinkeby or mainnet!

Tags: solidity, nft, the-graph

I try to deploy my subgraph on the Goerli network,
in the `subgraph.yaml` and subgraph studio, I select Goerli Network
but, when I run the deploy command it shows me this error:
[image]

what should I do!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Developer advocate from Chainstack here.

the Graph is undergoing a change to transform [the graph studio](https://thegraph.com/studio/) to the graph network. [Here](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/supported-networks/) they stated that:

> Remember that you will not be able to publish a subgraph that indexes
> a non-mainnet network to the decentralized Graph Network in Subgraph
> Studio.

You can try using their [hosted service](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/deploying/hosted-service/) though.

Or hosting your own [graph node](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node).

Or [our version of Subgraph](https://chainstack.com/subgraphs/), which is still in EA.